# efficient insert in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

Does anyone know a more efficient way of inserting a row into sqlite?
I am worried of split function.
Should I store the values in xml or json?
If you have any proposals, I would like to know.

my array of values is

```
private static final String[] inShopCategories = 
     {"Babies;5;@drawable/ic_launcher",
"Fruit / Vegetables;3;@drawable/ic_launcher",
"Meat / Fisth;2;@drawable/ic_launcher"};
```

and my code is:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        //create table
        db.execSQL(cShopCateg);

        //insert default shopping categories with InsertHelper
        InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, tShopCateg);
        final int nameCol = ih.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        final int priorityCol = ih.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRIORITY);
        final int iconCol = ih.getColumnIndex(KEY_ICON);

        for(int i=-1,l=inShopCategories.length; ++i<l;){
            ih.prepareForInsert();
            String[] s = inShopCategories[i].split(";");
            ih.bind(nameCol, s[0]);
            ih.bind(priorityCol, s[1]);
            ih.bind(iconCol, s[2]);
            ih.execute();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> do anyone know a more efficient way of inserting row in sqlite?

Yes.

> i am worried of split function

That makes sense. You are wasting CPU cycles for no good reason.

> should i store the values in xml or json?

Those would waste more CPU cycles for no good reason.

> if you have any proposals, i would like to know.

Option #1: Get rid of all this code and pre-package your database, with its data already inserted, with your app, using something like [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Option #2: Have your `String[]` be full SQL `INSERT` statements and execute those, rather than going through a lot of parsing and concatenating to reach the same end.

Option #3: If somebody is pointing a gun at your head to use `InsertHelper`, have a two-dimensional `String` array (`String[][]`) for your rows and columns.